# Angular way to set Iframe src to base64 data

Tags: html, angularjs, iframe

I am trying to set Iframe source to base64 data contains PDF in following format,

**JS**

```
$http.get('../../xyz', { token: $scope.token})
   .success( function(response) {
       $scope.reportBase64String = 'data:application/pdf;base64,' + response.data;
   });
```

**HTML**

```
<iframe id="report" ng-src="{{reportBase64String}}"></iframe>
```

**ERROR**

Blocked loading resource from url not allowed by $sceDelegate policy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can go through the doc of Strict Contextual Escaping [Doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce)

but for now i would recommend you to inject `$sce`
and the file path which you provided change it to

```
$scope.reportBase64String=$sce.trustAsResourceUrl('data:application/pdf;base64,' + response.data);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Angular 2+

.ts file

```
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

this.http.get(url).subscribe(res => {
    if (res.data) { //res.data must be base64 data format
      this.src = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('data:application/pdf;base64,' + res.data);
    }
  }
```

.html file

```
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" [src]="mainfestHtml"></iframe>
```

If would like to hide toolbar then just add #toolbar=0 after base64 string like

```
this.src = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('data:application/pdf;base64,' + res.data + '#toolbar=0&navpanes=0');
```